# Unable to find the repositories in dependencies tab of POM.xml in eclipse Oxygen 3.3

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm very new to Maven and Spring, when i'm trying to add dependencies from the pom file and trying to search for the reposotories i couldn't find any. Can you tell me what's the issue ?
[Please look at this attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnCQP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change Settings in Eclipse. Try following

Go to

> Window|Preference|Maven

The checkboxes

> Download Artifact Source;
>   Download repository index updates on startup;
>   Update Maven projects on startup;
>   Automatically update Maven projekts configuration;

must be checked.